# Stable set of infinity with complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

I need some help with a question from my textbook for dynamical systems with complex numbers.

Let $q_c(z)=z^2+c$.

a) Prove that if $|z|\geq |c|$ and $|z|>2$, then $|q_c(z)|>|z|$ and $z$ is in the stable set of infinity.

b) Use part (a) to show that if $|c|>2$, then $q_c^n(0)$ tends to $\infty$.

The book has an example that if I let $|z|>|c|+1$ I can show that $q(z)=z^{2}+c \geq |z^{2}|-|c| \geq (|c|+1)^{2}-|c|=|c|^{2}+|c|+1$ and then by induction it would follow that this $z$ is in the stable set of infinity since the right side of this equation would get larger by every iteration. Now I'm thinking, in a same fashion, that since $|z|\geq 2>|c|$ it would follow that $|z^{2}+c| \geq |4|+|c|$ and then each iteration would get larger and thus approach infinity. Is 
But it doesn't feel legit, I feel like I'm missing the point. I would like some suggestions/answers on how to do this..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards (a), we have that $|z|\geq |c|$ and $|z|>2$ imply
$$|q_c(z)|\geq |z|^2-|c|= |z|(|z|-1)-|c|+|z|>|c|(2-1)-|c|+|z|=|z|.$$
For (b), if $|c|>2$ then $f(z):=|q_c(z)|-|z|>0$ for $|z|\geq |c|$.
Note that as  $|z|\to +\infty$
$$f(z)=|q_c(z)|-|z|\geq |z|^2-|c|-|z|\to +\infty,$$ therefore the non-negative continuous function $f$ has a positive minimum value $a>0$ over the closed set $|z|\geq |c|$.
Therefore if $|z|\geq |c|$ then $|q_c(z)|\geq |z|+a\geq |c|$ and
$$|q_c^n(0)|=|q_c^{n-1}(c)|\geq |q_c^{n-2}(c)|+a\geq  |q_c^{n-3}(c)|+2a\geq
|c|+(n-1)a\to +\infty$$
which proves (b).

Comment: but $|c| \ngtr 2$, but $|z|>2$, so $|c|$ could be smaller than 2.

Comment: In (b), we assume that $|c|>2$, therefore if $|z|\geq |c|$ then $|z|>2$ and we can use a).

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks!